# Thread-safety of a simple & complex stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concurrency, innodb, temp-tables

For the purpose of this question, I am defining a **complex** stored procedure as 'one involving (at least) one cursor and (at least) one loop to insert data into a temporary table and then return the records from the said temporary table'.

When working on such a complex stored procedure, I was told that when two different users logged into the application perform operations which invoke the same procedure, as the procedure, being complex, can take time up to few seconds (~10 seconds) to finish execution, then the results may not faithful on a per-user basis. That is, the results may get mixed up and one user may see the results intended for the other user, as they try to access the *same* temporary table.

The recommendation was to use a unique system-generated identifier for each user in order to distinguish the result sets for each user.

Now, I'd like to know the following:-

1. Can this concurrency problem be avoided by using any table or database engine configuration settings?
2. Is this a violation of one or more ACID properties? How does using a full ACID compliant database engine (such as InnoDB, the one I am using) impact this question?
3. In the case of a **simple** stored procedure, one which involves only a single `SELECT` statement over a join of multiple tables, but no temporary tables, when the execution time is almost always under a second, is concurrency still a problem?

Comment: Almost always a Cursor can be replaced by a single SQL statement.  Challenge yourself to do that _first_.  If you can't then maybe we can discuss actual code.

Comment: @RickJames: Thanks for the comment. I agree totally with your point. It seems that I have misunderstood the question originally. The issue seems to be related to the use of a temporary table common for all 'threads'. So, I've updated the question and it is now purely a theoretical question. See if you can answer it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, "cursor" is irrelevant.  You just want a long-running Stored Procedure running simultaneously in multiple connections by the same user.

A *connection* (alias a *session*) is the unit of "independence".  An entity (such as a table) is either specific to the connection, or global to the world (aside from permission problems).  There is nothing "specific to a *user*".

A `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` is unique to the *connection* creating it.  Ditto for `last_insert_id()`.  These are "thread-safe" in that the "connection" is the "thread".

If you want to have multiple connections (same user or not) access the same "temporary" table, then it is up to you to create a non-`TEMPORARY` table and somehow know the name of that table.